# If I offer a bounty on someone else's question, can I still choose who gets the bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to offer a bounty on a question by someone else, I would really like the issue fixed too and don't want to open a duplicate question.

If I offer the bounty, do I get to choose the recipient of the bounty from any answers or is that still up to the OP?

[This is the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778799/ubuntu-16-04-gnome-conky-does-not-work-right) and I ask because I would like to set a bit of a narrower criteria, i.e. A user could just post a fixed config file for a specific theme and others could use it to modify any other theme they liked as I don't think this is an issue that can just be fixed globally.

I think if I offer 100 rep, we have users who could fix this quite quickly with a little incentive.

Comment: Well, I would hope so, but there's only one way to find out! ;)

Comment: I hope so to @ParanoidPanda I can't offer it until tomorrow anyway, I am just worried that as bounty's attract bad answers and the OP was new, they might accept the first half arsed answer that comes along and waste my bounty if I don't have control over it.

Comment: To anyone reading this who is interested, the bounty is now active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have complete control over who the bounty goes to. The OP has no say.

Comment: Thanks seth, good to know.